# PDO update not working, although no errors

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update

I appreciate that there are tons of similar questions but after trawling though them, I still haven't found an example that can help me.

I am sending the following JSON array:

```
 {
  "operation": "question_edit",
  "question": {
  "questionStringEdit": "This is a question",
  "question_id": "3"
  }
}
```

Which is eventually sent to this PDO update query

```
public function editQuestion($questionStringEdit, $question_id){


$sql = "UPDATE question SET questionString =: $questionStringEdit WHERE question_id =: $question_id;";


// Prepare statement
$query = $this ->conn ->prepare($sql);

// execute the query
$query->execute();


if($query){


    return true;


} else {

    return false;

}
```

}

This is my table in my database

```
CREATE TABLE question(
question_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
unique_id varchar(23) NOT NULL,
questionString varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (question_id)
);
```

**Things I've tried to solve the issue**

I have used Postman and added `var_dump($sql);` which echos `'UPDATE question SET questionString =: This is a question WHERE question_id =: 3;'`. To me, this query looks like it should update in my DB but when I check it, nothing has been changed.

I have tried adding quotes round my string variable $questionStringEdit but that hasn't helped either.

I haven't added my connection details since I have a ton of queries that are all adding just fine - I've just hit a brick wall here.

Postman tells me that my queries are adding successfully - no idea what is happening.

If someone can give me any tips or guidance, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PHP PDO Prepared Statement Place Holder Error

**Kindly follow my Prepared Statement to Avoid SQL Injection**

*Replace it with your Old Code*

```
//PDO Prepared statement by Ajmal Praveen
$sql = "UPDATE question SET questionString= :questionString WHERE question_id= :question_id";
$query = $this ->conn ->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(
':questionString' => $questionStringEdit,
':question_id' => $question_id
));
//Below You can modify as you need.
if($query){


    return true;


} else {

    return false;

}
```

Kindly update me if you are facing any issues... Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is working and uses the correct placeholders, thanks!

Comment: Really, Thanks for the Update :)

Always dont trust users If you are using in Production server kindly Filter and Sanitize Strings for Safer Much more.

and If you need any help Poke me.. :)

Comment: yeah, thanks again, I appreciate the help. I do have another similar question, where I am not getting an update in my DB but I am using filter & sanitize, not sure what the issue is but clearly I am doing something wrong!

Comment: Okay D.N.   Sure Kindly Search my name in FB its my real name, so you can find me, Msg me there Let me try to get you in live server.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use binding of parameters instead of string interpolation. 
It will both solve your problem and protect from SQL injection.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score -2):

Your query must look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE question SET questionString = '$questionStringEdit' WHERE question_id = '$question_id'";
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely been staring at this too long! All working.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not completely correct. Usage of unescaped values in the SQL query is the huge security hole.

Comment: @Alex, yes you're right, I was more aiming the question at figuring out what was going on and tried to make the query as simple as possible for my own sake at the time. I will however, add updated values.

Comment: It's not answering the question and is dangerous to do that.